# Sum the variable array values which depends on event

Tags: javascript, angularjs

good day to all of you. I am having trouble on how can I implement the logic of summing up the value of my indexed variable which changes on an event.

When the user has selected a value in select (the quantity is declared and has a default value of **1**) the **update()** will trigger and will compute the total_amount.

The problem I encountered is when I clicked **addNewField()** and new input has been created an input a new value to the added field, the **total_amount** is computing only that specific index field and not summing up all the indexed fields.

**JS file**

```
vm.update = function(index) {
    vm.amount[index] = vm.quantity[index] * vm.selectedItem[index].price;

    for(var i=0; i <= index; i++){
        var sum = 0;
        sum += parseInt(vm.amount[i]);
    }
    vm.total_amount = sum;
}

vm.addNewField = function(){   
    if(checkValue() == true){
        var index = vm.fields.length;
        vm.fields.push({'id': index });
        vm.quantity[index] = 1;
    }
}
```

**HTML file**

```
<div class="row" ng-repeat="field in vm.fields track by $index">
    <div class="form-group col-sm-8">
        <label>Item Name</label>
        <select ng-model="vm.selectedItem[$index]" ng-options="item as item.item_name for item in vm.items" ng-change="vm.update($index)" class="form-control">
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Quantity</label>
            <input type="number" class="form-control" ng-change="vm.update($index)" ng-model="vm.quantity[$index]" placeholder="123">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-1">
        <div  class="form-group">
            <a ng-show="$index != '0'" href="" ng-click="vm.removeField($index)" class="button"><i class="fa fa-lg fa-trash"></i> 
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="card-footer">
    <button type="button" ng-click="vm.addNewField()" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary "><i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i> Add Field</button>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <label><strong>Total Amount:</strong></label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6" >
        <label><strong>{{ vm.total_amount }}</strong></label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
       var sum = 0;

 for(var i=0; i <= index; i++){
    sum += parseInt(vm.amount[i]);
}
```

Sum should be outside loop